# Java file not working when sent over a network

Tags: java, tcp, client, mp3, server

So I was implementing client and socket for java. I wanted to send huge files on tcp through sockets and I was able to send files too but the only problem was the files on the other end were either not complete or not working. I have checked the bits are being transfered then what is the error.

**Client side:**

```html
   Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1056);
    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[1024];
    InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("abc.mp3");
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    int bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
    int len = 0;
    while((len = is.read(mybytearray)) != -1)
    {
    bos.write(mybytearray, 0, len);
    System.out.println("sending");
    }
  
    bos.close();
    sock.close();
```

**Server side:**

```html
  ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1056);
    while (true) {
      Socket s = ss.accept();
      PrintStream out = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
      String info = null;
      String request = null;
      System.out.println("sending");      
       String filename = "abc.mp3";
        File fi = new File(filename);
        InputStream fs = new FileInputStream(fi);
        int n = fs.available();
        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        out.println("Content_Length:" + n);
        out.println("");
        while ((n = fs.read(buf)) >= 0) {
          out.write(buf, 0, n);
             System.out.println("sending");
        }
        out.close();
        s.close();
        in.close();
  
  }
```

Comment: here is better exp of question hello, so I was implementing client and socket for java. I wanted to send huge files using TCP. I was able to send files but the files were either not complete or not working.the bits are being transfered then what is the error. It works fine for small txt files.

Answer (score 1):

When you are connected via TCP you create a network stream which you can read and write in, similar to all other streams you worked with. Writing a large amount of data to the stream is not a good idea, so I suggest you break the selected file into smaller packets in which each packet length is 1024 bytes (1KB) and then send all the packets to the server. The SendTCP function is as follows:(I have used Windows Forms to make things more obvious)

```
public void SendTCP(string M, string IPA, Int32 PortN)
{
    byte[] SendingBuffer = null
    TcpClient client = null;
    lblStatus.Text = "";
    NetworkStream netstream = null;
    try
    {
         client = new TcpClient(IPA, PortN);
         lblStatus.Text = "Connected to the Server...\n";
         netstream = client.GetStream();
         FileStream Fs = new FileStream(M, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
         int NoOfPackets = Convert.ToInt32
      (Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(Fs.Length) / Convert.ToDouble(BufferSize)));
         progressBar1.Maximum = NoOfPackets;
         int TotalLength = (int)Fs.Length, CurrentPacketLength, counter = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < NoOfPackets; i++)
         {
             if (TotalLength > BufferSize)
             {
                 CurrentPacketLength = BufferSize;
                 TotalLength = TotalLength - CurrentPacketLength;
             }
             else
                 CurrentPacketLength = TotalLength;
                 SendingBuffer = new byte[CurrentPacketLength];
                 Fs.Read(SendingBuffer, 0, CurrentPacketLength);
                 netstream.Write(SendingBuffer, 0, (int)SendingBuffer.Length);
                 if (progressBar1.Value >= progressBar1.Maximum)
                      progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Minimum;
                 progressBar1.PerformStep();
             }

             lblStatus.Text=lblStatus.Text+"Sent "+Fs.Length.ToString()+" 
                        bytes to the server";
             Fs.Close();
         }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
         netstream.Close();
         client.Close();
    }
}
```

As you can see, a TCP client and a network stream are being constructed and a network connection is initiated. After opening the selected file according to the buffer size which is 1024 bytes, the number of packets that are going to be sent is calculated. There are two other variables CurrentPacketLength and TotalLength. If the total length of the selected file is more than the buffer size the CurrentPacketLength is set to the buffer size, otherwise why send some empty bytes, so CurrentPacketLength is set to the total length of the file. After that, I subtract the current from the total length, so actually we can say total length is showing the total amount of data that has not been sent yet. The rest is pretty much straight forward, reading the data from the file stream and writing it to the SendingBuffer according to the CurrentPacketLength and writing the buffer to the network stream.

At the **server side**, the application is listening for an incoming connection:

```
public void ReceiveTCP(int portN)
{
    TcpListener Listener = null;
    try
    {
        Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, portN);
        Listener.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    byte[] RecData = new byte[BufferSize];
    int RecBytes;

    for (; ; )
    {
        TcpClient client = null;
        NetworkStream netstream = null;
        Status = string.Empty;
        try
        {                          
             string message = "Accept the Incoming File ";
             string caption = "Incoming Connection";
             MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
             DialogResult result;

             if (Listener.Pending())
             {
                  client = Listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                  netstream = client.GetStream();
                  Status = "Connected to a client\n";
                  result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, buttons);

                  if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
                  {
                       string SaveFileName=string.Empty;
                       SaveFileDialog DialogSave = new SaveFileDialog();
                       DialogSave.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";
                       DialogSave.RestoreDirectory = true;
                       DialogSave.Title = "Where do you want to save the file?";
                       DialogSave.InitialDirectory = @"C:/";
                       if (DialogSave.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                            SaveFileName = DialogSave.FileName;
                       if (SaveFileName != string.Empty)
                       {
                           int totalrecbytes = 0;
                           FileStream Fs = new FileStream
            (SaveFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                           while ((RecBytes = netstream.Read
                (RecData, 0, RecData.Length)) > 0)
                           {
                                Fs.Write(RecData, 0, RecBytes);
                                totalrecbytes += RecBytes;
                           }
                           Fs.Close();
                       }
                       netstream.Close();
                       client.Close();
                  }
             }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            //netstream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

A TCP listener is created and starts listening to the specified port. Again the buffer size is set to 1024 bytes. A TCP listener can pre check to see if there are any connections pending before calling the AcceptTcpClient method. It returns true if there are any pending connections. This method is a good way of avoiding the socket being blocked. Before reading anything from the network stream, a message box asks you if you want to accept the incoming connection, then a SaveFileDialog will be opened, and when you enter the file name plus extension, a file stream will be constructed and you start reading from the network stream and writing to the file stream. Create a thread in your code and run the receiving method in the created thread. I have sent more than 100 MB files in a LAN with the application.

For more details, check this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32633/Sending-Files-using-TCP).

Comment: "Writing a large amount of data to the stream is not a good idea."  Wrong.  Wrong.  Wrong.  You should write as large of chunks as you can and check the number-of-bytes-written result in case the system didn't accept it all.  Writing smaller chunks (like 1KiB) means you'll likely send out 1KiB packets which is smaller than the maximum packet size and less efficient on the network.

Comment: @BrianWhite Please do not judge a book by its cover. Read the whole answer and then you can do whatever you want like downvoting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

So, first you do this

```
int bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
```

That reads up to 1024 bytes into mybytearray.

You don't do anything with that and I don't understand why you are doing it. You never write those bytes so they get overwritten if the while loop reads anything.
Just delete that. The while loop should cover all of this.

Comment: did does not work and after that I wasn't even able to send text file. thanks though